# how to interpret HTML in XSL

Tags: html, xml, xslt, orbeon

I have the following xml

```
<results>
    <first-name>Carl<first-name>
    <data><b> This is carl's data </b></data>
</results>
```

How do I include the bold tags which is present in the <data> tag to be a part of the output but rendered as an HTML

When I say `<xsl:value-of select="results/data"/>` The output is

```
<b> This is carl's data </b>
```

I want to achieve "This is carl's data" as the output in bold.

Comment: With `xsl:value-of` the result can't be `<b> This is carl's data </b>`. Please, clarify that. Do you have `<data><![CDATA[<b> This is carl's data </b>]]></data>` or `<data>&lt;b> This is carl's data &lt;/b></data>` in your source?

Answer (score 1):

Well `<xsl:copy-of select="results/data/node()"/>` is a start but if the requirement is part of a larger problem then you are better off writing a template for `data` elements which uses `apply-templates` to push the child nodes through some template(s) for copying HTML elements through to the output.

Comment: copy-of did not work, I do not want the HTML elements in the output, I want the HTML element to be interpreted and applied on the output

Comment: Sorry, "did not work" does not tell me exactly what you have tried. Please explain in more detail what kind of format your stylesheet is supposed to create, which output method you use, how you run the stylesheet and how you look at the output. If you want to output a HTML document then the copy-of on the contents of the `data` element should output the `b` element and any HTML user agent ("browser") would render bold text.

Comment: If Alejandro is right then doing `<xsl:value-of select="results/data" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>` can help (as long as the XSLT processor serializes the result tree, of the current browsers Firefox/Mozilla does not do that).

Comment: @Martin: Sorry that I didn't explain it in detail, The input is the xml and the output required is the first name i.e., Carl and **This is carl's data**. I tried disable-output-escaping="yes" as well but that too displays `<b>This is carl's data</b>, I want it to display **This is carl's data**

Comment: @Alejandro: Yes, I have embedded HTML in the data tag, and I do not want the HTML to be displayed as is but I want that to be interpreted

Comment: SDS, how do you run the XSLT, do you do that in the browser (i.e. simply by loading an XML with `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sheet.xsl"?>`)? Which browser is that? Or which XSLT processor do you use? I am afraid depending on your input and output some of our suggestions should have made a difference, we need to know more details to find out why nothing helps.

Comment: @Martin, I'm using oxf:xslt processor from [orbeon](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/processors-xslt-jaxp). Tried it on Firefox, IE, Chrome and Safari.

Comment: What is the `xsl:output method` in your stylesheet?

Comment: `<xsl:value-of select="results/data"/>` is what I'm using to display the result

Comment: Does your `xsl:stylesheet` element have an `xsl:output` child element? What is the `method` attribute value of that element? Do you output HTML 4 or XHTML 1.0? What is the name and namespace of the root element of your transformation result?

Comment: I don't have an xsl:output, The output from this processor is fed to oxf:xhtml-to-pdf from [orbeon](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/processors-pdf-extraction). I have no clue whether HTML 4 or XHTML 1.0 is the output of oxf:xsl processor

Comment: I don't know how to help with that orbeon specific problem. If the input is as posted then my `xsl:copy-of` suggestion should work, here is a sample document http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2011041601.xml that uses the stylesheet http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2011041601Xsl.xml which uses `copy-of`. That way all browsers I have tested (Firefox, IE, Opera, Safari) do render the text in the `b` element bold.

Comment: You should also consider to tag your question with the orbeon tag as that way hopefully someone with expertise on orbeon and its XSLT support will be able to tell what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure someone will let me know if I am being naive:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/results">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="first-name">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="data">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="b">
    <b>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </b>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```